# How call volume slider function in different keyFrames with different sound channels?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have this code for my volume slider:

```
var stVolume:SoundTransform=new SoundTransform();
slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,volslider);
function volslider(ev:SliderEvent):void
{
    stVolume.volume=(ev.value/100);
    sch1.soundTransform = stVolume;
}
```

I have many frames with different sound channels. How can I call this function with specific sound channels in each frame like shc2, sch3 and others instead use repeatedly all of function?
Is it possible send SoundChannel name whit eventListener for example:

```
slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,volslider(/*something i don't know*/,sch10));
```

Comment: create a global var and assign the channel you want to modify to it

Comment: I know this but I don't know how send this variable as a function arguments!!!

Answer (score 0):

An AudioSource is attached to a GameObject for playing back sounds in a 3D environment. In order to play 3D sounds you also need to have a AudioListener. The audio listener is normally attached to the camera you want to use. Whether sounds are played in 3D or 2D is determined by AudioImporter settings.